# PHP File Upload Acting Strange

Tags: php, image, file, upload, jpeg

Earlier this file upload was working fine, but now im just making it fit better into what im needing but now it dosnt seam to want to work.
Once submitting the form it goes to a blank white page, but when commenting out the image upload script the form acts as it should and it successfully submits the rest of the form data.

```
if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_FILES["accountimage"]["name"])) {
    //$imagemessagebad = 'Error - Please Select An Image!';
} else {
    $fileName = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($username)).'-accountimage.jpg';
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["accountimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $fileType = $_FILES["accountimage"]["type"];
    $fileSize = $_FILES["accountimage"]["size"];
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["accountimage"]["error"];
    if(!$fileTmpLoc) {
        $imagemessagebad = 'Error - Please Select An Image!';
        exit();
    } elseif(!preg_match("/.(jpg)$/i", $fileName) ) {   
        $imagemessagebad = 'Error - Wrong Image Type!';
        echo('222');
        unlink($fileTmpLoc);
        exit(); 
    } elseif($fileErrorMsg == 1) {
        $imagemessagebad = 'Error Proccessing Image!';
        echo('333');
        exit();
    }
    $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "/xampp/htdocs/techbite/admin/accounts/$fileName");
    if($moveResult != true) {
        $imagemessagebad = 'Error Uploading Image!';
        echo('444');
        unlink($fileTmpLoc);
        exit();
    } else {
        unlink($fileTmpLoc);
    }
    if($fileErrorMsg == 0) {
        $imagemessagegood = 'The image '.$fileName.'-logo.jpg has been uploaded!';
    } else {
        $imagemessagebad = 'Error Uploading Image!';
    }
}
```

I have printed the array of the file on the white blank page it generates after submitting the form and here is the info it gives of any jpg i upload:

```
Array ( [name] => uploadtest.jpg [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 )
```

As you can see not all the info is there and error = 1

The upload script also gets stuck straight onto the 'if(!$fileTmpLoc) {' part.

Anyone know whats happening?

Comment: Error reporting will tell you what's going wrong. Make sure you have `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `display_errors = On` in your `php.ini` file. Don't forget to restart your web server if you make changes

Comment: Also, an error value of "1" means *"The uploaded file exceeds the `upload_max_filesize` directive in `php.ini`"*. See http://php.net/manual/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: I have recently edited the php.ini and changed the upload max filesize to 100M from 2M, but didnt know i had to restart the server when changing php.ini, i will try restarting it now :)

Comment: The restart worked great, thanks guys! Its always the small errors we do that makes the biggest problems!